# how to generates JCEKS keystore in android

Tags: android, security, keystore, android-keystore

I use

```
KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
```

But is make KeyStoreException

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: KeyStore JCEKS implementation not found
```

Reason is default security provider is bouncycastle in Android.
Therefore I use

```
KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS", "SunJCE");
```

But is make NoSearchProviderException

```
java.security.NoSearchProviderException: SunJCE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not include the SunJCE security provider and therefore JCEKS is not a supported Keystore type (neither is the older JKS format).

To create a KeyStore you can either choose the BouncyCastle Keystore

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
```

or, from Android 4.3, the new `AndroidKeyStore` based on OpenSSL decdicated to store app-private keys (more details [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#Security))

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
```

And if you have a JCEKS Keystore you will have to convert it to BKS format with keytool:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srcstoretype JCEKS -srckeystore my.keystore -srckeypass my_password -destprovidername BC -deststoretype BKS -destkeypass my_new_password -destkeystore my.bks
```