# Sun JCE and BouncyCastle Android incompatible encryption?

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle

I'm porting a working application that does encryption to Android.  The RSA encryption works within a single platform - the Android build can decrypt what was encrypted on the Android app.  But data encrypted on the Java application cannot be decrypted on Android.

Given the same inputs - same Private Key modulus and exponent, and same 256-byte input block, I'm getting different results using javax.crypto.Cipher as in...

```
public java.security.PrivateKey m_privateKey;

public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] input)
{
    Cipher cipher;
    byte[] cipherData = null;
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, m_privateKey);
    cipherData = cipher.doFinal(input);
    return cipherData;
}
```

It looks to me like this is a provider issue; debuggers report Android's cipher provider is com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider, BC version 1.49, while the application cipher provider is SunJCE version 1.7.

The keys also have a slightly different shape; their privateExponent and modulus match correctly, but on the application, m_privateKey is instantiated as a Sun RSA private key, 2048 bits.  On Android, it is com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAPrivateKey despite the declaration above.

I'm at a bit of a loss.  The application code works on Linux, Mac and Windows boxes, in both client and server environments, so I don't have a lot of flexibility on switching it around.  Any ideas on what to check to get Android's java/crypto to be compatible?

Edit to provide what owlstead requested...

For both, I used:

```
byte[] encodedPublic = rsaencUserKeys.m_publicKey.getEncoded();
byte[] encodedPrivate = rsaencUserKeys.m_privateKey.getEncoded();
byte[] testDataIn = new byte[]{25, 99, 76, 84, 7, 104, 27, 47, 120, 86, 83, 9, 56, 77, 0};
byte[] cryptoTest = rsaencUserKeys.Encrypt(testDataIn);
byte[] plainTest = rsaencUserKeys.Decrypt(cryptoTest);
```

The Application (Java) values:
Encoded Public Key:
[48, -126, 1, 34, 48, 13, 6, 9, 42, -122, 72, -122, -9, 13, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 3, -126, 1, 15, 0, 48, -126, 1, 10, 2, -126, 1, 1, 0, -88, -3, 17, -56, -93, -54, -29, 50, 23, -33, 20, -23, 107, 83, 5, 92, -52, -102, 119, 63, 106, -77, -84, -119, -39, -54, -37, -13, -57, -54, 127, -24, -121, 95, -120, 121, -3, 56, -125, -31, 56, 52, 91, 59, 64, 28, -33, 120, -12, -89, 86, -32, 111, 48, -1, -121, 23, 101, -122, -126, 26, -112, 82, 80, -126, -126, 59, -123, -107, -51, -85, 108, 100, -95, 123, 115, -3, -98, -44, -84, -39, -8, -110, -24, -20, -108, -49, 44, -13, -51, -92, 52, -30, -27, -75, 38, 105, -68, -28, 84, 113, 101, -3, -127, -56, 39, 121, 0, 50, 95, -94, -31, -46, 97, 84, 22, -38, 53, 34, -28, -79, 18, -110, 13, 63, -49, 13, 18, 49, 0, -120, 100, 91, -33, -50, -116, 69, 88, 112, 34, 115, -98, 67, 35, 55, 59, 54, 97, -6, -67, 10, -92, 110, -86, -24, 120, -81, 33, 105, -57, 67, -73, -24, -85, -118, 118, -69, -16, 11, 32, -32, 65, 123, 64, -90, -68, -40, -56, 96, 23, -14, 21, -49, -27, 108, 2, -8, -76, 15, 38, 34, -3, 64, 89, 117, -67, 125, -78, -79, -44, 47, 103, 81, 117, -13, -1, -96, -115, 37, -110, -36, -78, 80, -74, 24, 34, -15, -5, -31, -5, -117, 39, 49, 28, 70, 75, 4, -48, -49, 3, -14, 36, 0, -4, -111, -60, 96, -105, -2, -76, 101, -107, -105, -60, 66, 121, 33, -72, 8, 31, -3, -31, 52, 121, -90, -73, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1]

Encoded Private Key:
[48, -126, 2, 56, 2, 1, 0, 48, 13, 6, 9, 42, -122, 72, -122, -9, 13, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 4, -126, 2, 34, 48, -126, 2, 30, 2, 1, 0, 2, -126, 1, 1, 0, -88, -3, 17, -56, -93, -54, -29, 50, 23, -33, 20, -23, 107, 83, 5, 92, -52, -102, 119, 63, 106, -77, -84, -119, -39, -54, -37, -13, -57, -54, 127, -24, -121, 95, -120, 121, -3, 56, -125, -31, 56, 52, 91, 59, 64, 28, -33, 120, -12, -89, 86, -32, 111, 48, -1, -121, 23, 101, -122, -126, 26, -112, 82, 80, -126, -126, 59, -123, -107, -51, -85, 108, 100, -95, 123, 115, -3, -98, -44, -84, -39, -8, -110, -24, -20, -108, -49, 44, -13, -51, -92, 52, -30, -27, -75, 38, 105, -68, -28, 84, 113, 101, -3, -127, -56, 39, 121, 0, 50, 95, -94, -31, -46, 97, 84, 22, -38, 53, 34, -28, -79, 18, -110, 13, 63, -49, 13, 18, 49, 0, -120, 100, 91, -33, -50, -116, 69, 88, 112, 34, 115, -98, 67, 35, 55, 59, 54, 97, -6, -67, 10, -92, 110, -86, -24, 120, -81, 33, 105, -57, 67, -73, -24, -85, -118, 118, -69, -16, 11, 32, -32, 65, 123, 64, -90, -68, -40, -56, 96, 23, -14, 21, -49, -27, 108, 2, -8, -76, 15, 38, 34, -3, 64, 89, 117, -67, 125, -78, -79, -44, 47, 103, 81, 117, -13, -1, -96, -115, 37, -110, -36, -78, 80, -74, 24, 34, -15, -5, -31, -5, -117, 39, 49, 28, 70, 75, 4, -48, -49, 3, -14, 36, 0, -4, -111, -60, 96, -105, -2, -76, 101, -107, -105, -60, 66, 121, 33, -72, 8, 31, -3, -31, 52, 121, -90, -73, 2, 1, 0, 2, -126, 1, 0, 96, 69, -116, 84, 25, -68, 4, 35, 13, -90, 113, 107, 105, 81, 42, -60, -21, 107, 52, 116, 84, 125, 119, -42, 48, -43, 120, -23, 48, -15, 20, 93, -116, -127, -56, 102, 118, -12, 51, 109, -93, 111, 112, 106, 24, -28, 90, 11, -74, -107, 126, -48, -19, -121, -92, -117, 121, -80, -59, 40, 105, -87, -66, -69, 79, 30, -110, 122, 80, 21, -109, -117, 116, -24, -22, 67, -14, 65, 2, 56, 87, 21, 93, -36, -124, -85, 98, 59, -31, -55, 77, -69, 51, 104, 90, 3, 64, 73, -12, 106, -121, 15, -21, -108, 124, 74, -64, -116, 116, 38, 55, -51, 30, -27, -125, -38, 97, 5, -44, -109, 36, -83, -57, -74, -12, -101, 40, 126, 62, -81, -10, -61, -8, -113, -41, 17, -3, 84, 83, 94, 36, 3, 16, 8, -76, 74, 116, 85, 114, 30, 86, -51, 126, 122, 80, 52, 100, -41, -105, -20, 67, -128, -23, -26, -68, 118, 56, -35, 81, -15, -34, -32, 93, -88, 75, 92, 126, -1, 27, -117, 122, -81, -114, -32, -13, 94, -92, 121, 85, 39, 67, 42, -86, 95, 5, -19, 58, 127, -4, -34, 12, 35, 26, 6, 88, 112, -121, 24, -96, 96, 119, 119, -99, -72, -13, 6, 48, -78, -88, 106, 88, -13, -29, 9, 108, 124, 22, -110, 79, 83, -16, 108, -17, -88, 59, 19, -124, -75, 47, -71, 31, -35, 35, 54, 68, 43, -60, -36, 72, 52, 122, 119, 4, 101, -117, -127, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0]

CrytoTest:
[73, 116, -22, -83, -50, -107, 21, -119, -110, -63, 3, 48, 23, 3, -117, 66, -7, -114, -109, 52, 29, -97, -92, 23, 29, -48, 93, -119, -124, -111, -98, 54, 113, 46, -18, 39, -56, 1, -89, 70, -100, 78, -87, 98, -3, 6, 0, 79, 43, -127, 53, -75, -36, -104, -94, -86, 32, 38, -29, -98, 74, -124, 6, -42, 23, -7, -4, -90, 104, 55, -37, -26, -99, -119, 5, 13, -73, 6, 48, 58, -72, 95, -43, -76, -65, -35, 14, 113, 75, -55, 50, 5, 93, 96, 127, 48, -71, 70, 89, -52, -116, -21, 57, -13, -83, -81, -43, 99, 7, -38, 1, 3, -124, 55, 59, 54, -91, 85, -28, 92, 56, 109, -12, -44, 62, -13, -18, -59, 120, -113, -35, -86, -81, -65, -16, -29, -119, -120, 121, -20, -8, -6, 99, 46, 106, 11, 94, 51, 49, 105, -5, 104, -2, -65, -66, -100, -50, -124, 80, 59, -22, 62, 77, 106, 46, -14, 60, -11, 36, -119, 2, -74, -55, 1, 91, -63, -96, -113, -102, 53, -5, 33, 23, 82, 13, 77, 63, 84, -21, -37, 14, -1, 1, -5, -126, 66, 36, 74, -46, -76, -9, -76, 119, -116, 55, -50, -118, -6, -36, -32, -29, -57, -52, 8, 116, 39, -3, 47, -93, -1, -63, 105, 39, -3, -18, -109, -26, 94, 126, -16, -12, -24, 59, 37, -107, -92, -68, 35, -45, 116, -27, -33, -101, -85, -67, -67, 117, 59, -37, 49, -9, -4, -63, 63, 11, 89]
PlainTest: 
[25, 99, 76, 84, 7, 104, 27, 47, 120, 86, 83, 9, 56, 77, 0]

The Android values:
Encoded Public:
[48, -126, 2, 33, 48, 13, 6, 9, 42, -122, 72, -122, -9, 13, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 3, -126, 2, 14, 0, 48, -126, 2, 9, 2, -126, 1, 1, 0, -88, -3, 17, -56, -93, -54, -29, 50, 23, -33, 20, -23, 107, 83, 5, 92, -52, -102, 119, 63, 106, -77, -84, -119, -39, -54, -37, -13, -57, -54, 127, -24, -121, 95, -120, 121, -3, 56, -125, -31, 56, 52, 91, 59, 64, 28, -33, 120, -12, -89, 86, -32, 111, 48, -1, -121, 23, 101, -122, -126, 26, -112, 82, 80, -126, -126, 59, -123, -107, -51, -85, 108, 100, -95, 123, 115, -3, -98, -44, -84, -39, -8, -110, -24, -20, -108, -49, 44, -13, -51, -92, 52, -30, -27, -75, 38, 105, -68, -28, 84, 113, 101, -3, -127, -56, 39, 121, 0, 50, 95, -94, -31, -46, 97, 84, 22, -38, 53, 34, -28, -79, 18, -110, 13, 63, -49, 13, 18, 49, 0, -120, 100, 91, -33, -50, -116, 69, 88, 112, 34, 115, -98, 67, 35, 55, 59, 54, 97, -6, -67, 10, -92, 110, -86, -24, 120, -81, 33, 105, -57, 67, -73, -24, -85, -118, 118, -69, -16, 11, 32, -32, 65, 123, 64, -90, -68, -40, -56, 96, 23, -14, 21, -49, -27, 108, 2, -8, -76, 15, 38, 34, -3, 64, 89, 117, -67, 125, -78, -79, -44, 47, 103, 81, 117, -13, -1, -96, -115, 37, -110, -36, -78, 80, -74, 24, 34, -15, -5, -31, -5, -117, 39, 49, 28, 70, 75, 4, -48, -49, 3, -14, 36, 0, -4, -111, -60, 96, -105, -2, -76, 101, -107, -105, -60, 66, 121, 33, -72, 8, 31, -3, -31, 52, 121, -90, -73, 2, -126, 1, 0, 96, 69, -116, 84, 25, -68, 4, 35, 13, -90, 113, 107, 105, 81, 42, -60, -21, 107, 52, 116, 84, 125, 119, -42, 48, -43, 120, -23, 48, -15, 20, 93, -116, -127, -56, 102, 118, -12, 51, 109, -93, 111, 112, 106, 24, -28, 90, 11, -74, -107, 126, -48, -19, -121, -92, -117, 121, -80, -59, 40, 105, -87, -66, -69, 79, 30, -110, 122, 80, 21, -109, -117, 116, -24, -22, 67, -14, 65, 2, 56, 87, 21, 93, -36, -124, -85, 98, 59, -31, -55, 77, -69, 51, 104, 90, 3, 64, 73, -12, 106, -121, 15, -21, -108, 124, 74, -64, -116, 116, 38, 55, -51, 30, -27, -125, -38, 97, 5, -44, -109, 36, -83, -57, -74, -12, -101, 40, 126, 62, -81, -10, -61, -8, -113, -41, 17, -3, 84, 83, 94, 36, 3, 16, 8, -76, 74, 116, 85, 114, 30, 86, -51, 126, 122, 80, 52, 100, -41, -105, -20, 67, -128, -23, -26, -68, 118, 56, -35, 81, -15, -34, -32, 93, -88, 75, 92, 126, -1, 27, -117, 122, -81, -114, -32, -13, 94, -92, 121, 85, 39, 67, 42, -86, 95, 5, -19, 58, 127, -4, -34, 12, 35, 26, 6, 88, 112, -121, 24, -96, 96, 119, 119, -99, -72, -13, 6, 48, -78, -88, 106, 88, -13, -29, 9, 108, 124, 22, -110, 79, 83, -16, 108, -17, -88, 59, 19, -124, -75, 47, -71, 31, -35, 35, 54, 68, 43, -60, -36, 72, 52, 122, 119, 4, 101, -117, -127]

Encoded Private:
[48, -126, 2, 38, 2, 1, 0, 48, 13, 6, 9, 42, -122, 72, -122, -9, 13, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 4, -126, 2, 16, 48, -126, 2, 12, 2, 1, 0, 2, -126, 1, 1, 0, -88, -3, 17, -56, -93, -54, -29, 50, 23, -33, 20, -23, 107, 83, 5, 92, -52, -102, 119, 63, 106, -77, -84, -119, -39, -54, -37, -13, -57, -54, 127, -24, -121, 95, -120, 121, -3, 56, -125, -31, 56, 52, 91, 59, 64, 28, -33, 120, -12, -89, 86, -32, 111, 48, -1, -121, 23, 101, -122, -126, 26, -112, 82, 80, -126, -126, 59, -123, -107, -51, -85, 108, 100, -95, 123, 115, -3, -98, -44, -84, -39, -8, -110, -24, -20, -108, -49, 44, -13, -51, -92, 52, -30, -27, -75, 38, 105, -68, -28, 84, 113, 101, -3, -127, -56, 39, 121, 0, 50, 95, -94, -31, -46, 97, 84, 22, -38, 53, 34, -28, -79, 18, -110, 13, 63, -49, 13, 18, 49, 0, -120, 100, 91, -33, -50, -116, 69, 88, 112, 34, 115, -98, 67, 35, 55, 59, 54, 97, -6, -67, 10, -92, 110, -86, -24, 120, -81, 33, 105, -57, 67, -73, -24, -85, -118, 118, -69, -16, 11, 32, -32, 65, 123, 64, -90, -68, -40, -56, 96, 23, -14, 21, -49, -27, 108, 2, -8, -76, 15, 38, 34, -3, 64, 89, 117, -67, 125, -78, -79, -44, 47, 103, 81, 117, -13, -1, -96, -115, 37, -110, -36, -78, 80, -74, 24, 34, -15, -5, -31, -5, -117, 39, 49, 28, 70, 75, 4, -48, -49, 3, -14, 36, 0, -4, -111, -60, 96, -105, -2, -76, 101, -107, -105, -60, 66, 121, 33, -72, 8, 31, -3, -31, 52, 121, -90, -73, 2, -126, 1, 0, 96, 69, -116, 84, 25, -68, 4, 35, 13, -90, 113, 107, 105, 81, 42, -60, -21, 107, 52, 116, 84, 125, 119, -42, 48, -43, 120, -23, 48, -15, 20, 93, -116, -127, -56, 102, 118, -12, 51, 109, -93, 111, 112, 106, 24, -28, 90, 11, -74, -107, 126, -48, -19, -121, -92, -117, 121, -80, -59, 40, 105, -87, -66, -69, 79, 30, -110, 122, 80, 21, -109, -117, 116, -24, -22, 67, -14, 65, 2, 56, 87, 21, 93, -36, -124, -85, 98, 59, -31, -55, 77, -69, 51, 104, 90, 3, 64, 73, -12, 106, -121, 15, -21, -108, 124, 74, -64, -116, 116, 38, 55, -51, 30, -27, -125, -38, 97, 5, -44, -109, 36, -83, -57, -74, -12, -101, 40, 126, 62, -81, -10, -61, -8, -113, -41, 17, -3, 84, 83, 94, 36, 3, 16, 8, -76, 74, 116, 85, 114, 30, 86, -51, 126, 122, 80, 52, 100, -41, -105, -20, 67, -128, -23, -26, -68, 118, 56, -35, 81, -15, -34, -32, 93, -88, 75, 92, 126, -1, 27, -117, 122, -81, -114, -32, -13, 94, -92, 121, 85, 39, 67, 42, -86, 95, 5, -19, 58, 127, -4, -34, 12, 35, 26, 6, 88, 112, -121, 24, -96, 96, 119, 119, -99, -72, -13, 6, 48, -78, -88, 106, 88, -13, -29, 9, 108, 124, 22, -110, 79, 83, -16, 108, -17, -88, 59, 19, -124, -75, 47, -71, 31, -35, 35, 54, 68, 43, -60, -36, 72, 52, 122, 119, 4, 101, -117, -127]

Crypto Test:
[114, 116, 59, -51, -71, 99, 66, -34, 13, -31, 119, 8, -80, 107, 78, -67, 96, -122, -66, 122, 41, -114, -29, 105, -60, -38, 114, 101, -90, 5, 115, 96, -66, 4, 41, -48, 7, -77, -9, 47, -9, -2, -122, -60, -76, -58, -56, -116, 122, -7, -68, -4, 88, -77, 47, -109, -46, 44, -51, 57, 73, -21, -64, 10, 57, 64, -80, -85, 107, 21, 62, 42, -74, 49, -95, -37, 24, 38, 107, 83, 86, 70, -108, -82, -18, -77, -53, -128, 9, -32, 112, -122, 114, 24, 107, 89, -4, -43, 117, -97, -52, 95, 35, -1, -70, 57, 109, 64, 27, 51, -80, 63, -91, 6, 108, -10, -104, 111, 7, -80, 42, -3, 26, 92, 11, -1, 77, 19, 22, 66, 103, 119, 61, 8, -7, -83, 107, 0, 44, 60, -93, 22, -125, 87, -107, 90, -112, -16, 89, 83, 96, -78, -13, 15, 27, 95, 100, -122, 48, 63, -127, 2, -128, 124, -90, -52, -98, -78, -43, -112, -122, -20, -95, 1, 97, -51, -31, 17, -110, 114, 123, 116, -76, -118, 90, -93, -70, 68, 51, -114, 15, -49, 127, 85, 55, -14, -14, 76, 85, 37, -44, -72, 0, 114, 87, -87, -6, 33, 37, 4, -32, 117, 29, 47, 118, -42, 119, -99, 64, 62, -30, 98, -37, 23, -59, 84, -9, -120, -31, 99, -14, -85, -21, -100, 120, 18, -15, 83, 96, 123, -114, 16, 34, 24, -78, -38, -126, -13, 111, -43, 112, -126, -115, 1, -53, -32]

Plain Test:
[23, -76, -95, 117, 34, -100, 103, -120, -78, 111, -95, -9, 60, -110, 103, 81, -87, 43, 15, 84, -43, -31, -31, 24, -9, 53, 98, 120, -2, 46, -3, 78, 62, -112, -100, 104, -33, 60, 127, -128, -85, 24, -42, 47, -112, 88, -88, 64, -122, 29, -99, 13, -90, -27, -41, 87, 39, 28, 70, -89, -92, 76, 99, -116, -122, 85, -86, 8, 13, 2, 61, 6, -106, 66, -14, -100, -117, -26, -95, -106, 97, 40, -64, -62, 88, 35, -50, 121, 1, 10, 40, 106, -80, -37, -72, 69, -17, 81, 74, -48, -120, 28, -58, 76, 59, 126, -113, 126, -117, -51, -34, 120, -67, -17, -28, 86, -80, 40, 96, -15, -117, -123, 126, -3, 9, 67, -16, 84, 98, -75, 41, 79, 118, 1, 38, 6, 79, 88, -8, -82, -104, 87, -42, 16, 64, 77, -84, 117, -95, 61, -33, 66, -117, -20, -95, 105, -59, 97, -35, -102, 110, 56, -52, -3, 75, 57, -95, 37, -115, 95, -78, -108, -106, 97, 16, 22, -90, 114, -8, 4, -97, -6, 97, 123, 96, -58, -46, -46, 44, 27, 24, -52, -63, 21, -92, -40, -41, -92, 103, -24, -58, 47, -96, -14, -100, -50, 121, 18, 86, 26, 42, 102, 5, -53, -65, 64, 111, -78, 117, -103, -24, 36, 95, -54, 69, -124, -112, 99, -62, -113, -58, -5, -93, 80, 24, 76, 121, -41, 31, -61, 47, 0, -114, 12, -7, -6, -112, 19, -124, -41, -88, -6, -41, 57, 78, -56]

Comment: Could you create a key pair, publish the public/private key pair (as e.g. `getEncoded()` performed on the keys, then converted to hex or base 64) and a generated ciphertext? I can guess what's wrong, but it would require to setup my Android environment to validate it otherwise.

Comment: Maybe SunJCE and BC default to different padding? I'm not sure if this is the case, but it's worth specifying explicitly anyway. SunJCE defaults to `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` but `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding` would be more secure.

Comment: @ntoskrnl Yeah, that's what was what I'm hinting at. Lately though, I post such a comment, and then the asker starts to look into it and posts the solution himself. I'm now at 11 (correct, as far as I know) answers without any points and it is starting to itch.

Comment: Owlstead, I've added the data you requested.  I can see that the Public and Private keys don't match using "getEncoded()", but am unclear as to why, considering that their exponents and moduluses match; perhaps there is different baggage between the SunJCE and the BouncyCastle keys?

Comment: The Sun private key encoding looks like a correct PKCS#8 key, albeit with the CRT fields set to 0. The Android private key encoding looks like a half-assed, incorrect attempt at PKCS#8. It starts out correct then jams the private exponent immediately after the modulus and then its done. So I have to wonder how you transported keys from/to the Android and Java code. I have to say the Android stuff looks buggy, though I'd be curious to see what `getFormat()` returns on Android.

Comment: Greg, thanks for that.  It could be that I am not instantiating the Android key correctly, though the same code is being used in Android and application.

How -should- I be plugging the key data in, to use the same effective key across the two platforms?

Comment: I'm not an expert but it seems that using a BKS keystore may be available on both Android and standard Java, or you can convert from one to the other as in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341745/how-to-generates-jceks-keystore-in-android) question.

Comment: @GregS Funny enough *Bouncy* itself cannot decode the private key from the given PKCS#8 specification, if that's what it is. TCat, we need more info how you generated that value.

Comment: My plaintext (testDataIn) is only 15 bytes!  It IS the key.  The symmetric portion (which is working fine) just doesn't show in this example.

Comment: Ah, whoops, my bad, removing comment. I'll check tomorrow.

Comment: @owlstead That may be the problem.  How do I get a key from the desktop JCE compatible form (sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateKeyImpl) into the Android Bouncy Castle form (com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAPrivateKey)?